# Can't verifiy contract on Etherscan

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethers.js, etherscan

Everytime I upload my .json and the bytecode I am met with the same following error message on Etherscan.  Error! Invalid constructor arguments provided. Please verify that they are in ABI-encoded format. Or if I tweak the code i am met with this message, S"orry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for '' does NOT match the Contract Creation Code for Address 0x19b493108a212c53e825b2c5c6499f9d2e83fa2a.
Unable to Verify Contract Source Code."

[image]

Comment: You can use a tool like this https://abi.hashex.org/ to encode the constructor parameters. You haven't provided enough details to suggest another solutions.